# Latitude and Longitude for ajax call - Html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm trying to get the user current latitude and longitude and use it on an ajax call.
I have an array of cities and functions that get the users location, but somehow the variables are not getting any value.

Here is some code:

```
function getLng(){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(lng, error);
}

 function getLat(){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(lat, error);
}

function error(err){
console.warn('Error('+err.code+'):'+err.message);
}


function lat(position){
var crd = position.coords;
return crd.latitude;
}

 function lng(position){
  var crd = position.coords;
  return crd.longitude;
}
```

My object is like this:

```
 {
id:'currentLocation',
name:'Current Location',
lat: getLat(),
lng: getLng(),
lastUpdated: -1,
weatherData: null
}
```

And my ajax call is like this:
function getWeatherDataForCityId(city){

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/<apikey>/' + city.lat +","+city.lng+"?units=si",
jsonp:'callback', 
dataType:'jsonp', 
success:function(data){
(stuff...)
```

I don't know why but the city.lat keep coming as 'undefined'.

I'm allowing the browser to share my location.(I'm on firefox)

Can someone help?

Comment: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, so you're using it all wrong

Comment: Where are you defining `city`? `var city = {};`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to use getCurrentPosition

```
function success(position) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/<apikey>/' + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "?units=si",
        jsonp:'callback', 
        dataType:'jsonp', 
        success:function(data){
            (stuff...)
        }
    });
}

function failure() {
    console.warn('Error('+err.code+'):'+err.message);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, failure);
```